# Get key from collection item

Tags: php, laravel, collections

How do I get the key from a collection item?

`$posts= Post::all();`

Example (doesn't work):

`$key = $posts->where('id', $id)->getKey();`

Comment: You already know the key is `id` as you're using it in your `where` query?

Comment: A key in a collection is different from the `id` of a particular model.

Comment: @kjdion84 show the collection, please and how do you get it.

Comment: I know I can use a `foreach` loop, wondering if it can be done without one. I updated OP.

Comment: @kjdion84 `all()` will return a standard collection without keys. Please show the collection and give an example of what key exactly are you talking about.

Comment: Provide an  example of what you want. to which "key" do you refer..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `all()` will return a collection without keys. If you're talking about integer keys like 0, 1, 2 etc, use the `search()` method:

```
$key = $posts->search(function($i) use($id) {
    return $i->id === $id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `$post_ids = Post::pluck('id');`

That grabs just the `id` column from all the `Post` records and returns them as a collection.

If you want just a plain array, add toArray():

`$post_ids = Post::pluck('id')->toArray();`